# When to plant a cutting

Tags: houseplants, propagation, cuttings

I have a hoya cutting that started rooting a couple of weeks ago. I read online, that I should plant a cutting when the roots are about 5 cm long. But those roots in the photo in the article were very fine. My hoya has a couple long roots.

So I'm wondering, is my hoya ready for potting or should I wait?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cutting is ready to be potted. When there are a couple of 5-7 cm long roots, you could usually pot a cutting up. When the roots start branching as on your plant, you could definitely pot it up.

Make sure to keep the freshly potted plant's soil moist in the first couple of weeks so that the "water" roots could adapt to the new environment.

Comment: Should I start with a small pot and replant it when the time comes or can I plant it directly into a big pot?

Comment: @MysteriousChallenger Start small otherwise your would risk overwatering. A big pot would not dry out enough with such a young plant.